# get comparison of sales in 2020 and 2021 for each store name

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to get a comparison of sales in 2020 and 2021 for each store name and need to create a graph that shows trends of sales 2020-2021. currently, I'm using this query, but still not sure about the correct result. can anyone help?

```
with t1 as
(
    select  distinct store_name as store,
            extract (year from date) as year,
            cast(sum (sale_dollars) as int64) as total_sales
    from `bigquery-public-data.iowa_liquor_sales_forecasting.2020_sales_train`
    group by 1,2
    
),
t2 as 
(
    select distinct store_name as store,
           extract (year from date) as year,
           cast(sum (sale_dollars) as int64) as total_sales
    from `bigquery-public-data.iowa_liquor_sales_forecasting.2021_sales_predict`
    group by 1,2
)
select * from t1
union all
select * from t2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to compare both numbers, you can use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` and have both number alongside in a result set row

THE `FULL OUTER JOIN` is used here as it is for me not clear, if all rows  from t1 are also present in t2, so a test with other JOIN should be done

```
with t1 as
(
    select  distinct store_name as store,
            extract (year from date) as year,
            cast(sum (sale_dollars) as int64) as total_sales
    from `bigquery-public-data.iowa_liquor_sales_forecasting.2020_sales_train`
    group by 1,2
    
),
t2 as 
(
    select distinct store_name as store,
           extract (year from date) as year,
           cast(sum (sale_dollars) as int64) as total_sales
    from `bigquery-public-data.iowa_liquor_sales_forecasting.2021_sales_predict`
    group by 1,2
)
SELECT 
    COALESCE(t1.store,t2.store) as store,
    COALESCE(t1.year,t2.year) as year,
    t1.total_sales as total_sales_2020,
    t2.total_sales as total_sales_2021
FROM t1 FULL OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.store = t2.store AND t1.year = t2.year
```

Comment: thank you for the feedback. i appreciate it. i think I need practice more!